# Importing multiple files with filename conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, import, string-manipulation

I have multiple pictures I would like to import all at once. The filenames range from "000001.tif" to "000200.tif." I am having a hard time importing multiple images after looking up the filenames and modifying which ranges I would like  to import.

So far I've done the following:

```
names=FileBaseName /@ FileNames["*.tif"];
Flatten@ToExpression@StringSplit[names, ","];
Select[%, 20 <= # <= 22 &]
```

{"20", "21", "22"}

```
n = ToString /@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@%;
nn = StringTemplate["0000``"] /@ n
```

{"000020", "000021", "000022"}

From here when I try to import these files, mathematica merges them into one text.

```
Import[nn <> ".tif"]
```

Import::nffil: File 000020000021000022.tif not found during Import.

How can I import from a string and grab multiple files? And when I try to change the string {"000020", "000021", "000022"} to a list, I always loose the 0s.

Any help is very appreciated, thanks

Comment: `Import[#<>".tif"]&/@nn`

Answer (score 5):

### From a list of substrings

```
Import[
    StringTemplate["``.TIF"]@StringPadLeft[#,6,"0"]
    ,"TIF"
]& /@ {"20","21","22"}
```

### Search for files with a pattern name

Here I save not only the data (image), but also some meta-data.

```
ClearAll[alldata];
alldata = Table[
    With[
        {
            filename=StringTemplate["``.TIF"]@ToString@NumberForm[k,{6,0},NumberPadding->"0"]
        },
        If[
            FileExistsQ[filename],
            <|
                "name"->filename, 
                "data"->Import[filename, "TIF"]
            |>,
            Nothing
        ]
    ]
    ,{k,100}
]
```

or

### From a list of files that exist

Even more metadata

```
ClearAll[fn,alldata];
alldata=Table[
    <|
        "name"-> fn,
        "size"-> FileSize[fn],
        "data"->Import[fn,"TIF"]
    |>
    ,{fn,FileNames["*.TIF"]}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to import all the files in some given directory. Here is a simple example with just 2 files:

```
dir = "d:/tmp/t2";
names = FileNames[All, dir];
Import[#] & /@ names
```